# приведение задания к цепочке типов

Tags: f#

такой вопрос... по заданию мне требуется привести данный код к следующей цепочке типов: `int -> float -> float`, но мне это не удается ( буду рад любым разъяснениям!

```
let vat n x = if 0.0 <= n && n <= 100.0 then (n / 100.0) * x else 0.0
let n_perc = vat 1.0
printfn "%f" (n_perc 100.0)
```

Comment: `let vat n x = if 0 <= n && n <= 100 then (float n / 100.0) * x else 0.0`

Comment: спасибо за дополнение!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`F#` строго типизированный язык, который в большинстве случаев запрещает неявные преобразования типов. Это значит, что вы не можете передавать значение типа `int` в функцию ожидающую нецелочисленное значение.

Вам придется переписать функцию с тем учетом, чтобы тип `n` в действительности был `int`, а не `float`:

```
let vat n x = 
    if 0 <= n && n <= 100 
    then (float n / 100.0) * x 
    else 0.0

let n_perc = vat 1

printfn "%f" (n_perc 100.0)
```

Небольшое дополнение:

То, что вы называете "цепочкой типов":

```
int -> float -> float
```

обычно называется сигнатурой функции.

Для лучшего понимая F# и функционального подхода в целом я рекомендую следующий цикл статей:

[Функциональное мышление. Часть 1](https://habr.com/ru/company/microsoft/blog/415189/)

Или, если английский для вас не является проблемой, то исключительно полезный сайт

[fsharpforfunandprofit](https://fsharpforfunandprofit.com)

Comment: ... не мог раньше ответить, огромное спасибо!!!